# Magento2: How do I get products back order setting?

Tags: magento-2.1

I am trying to add a block in `catalog_product_view.xml` to display special info when back orders are allowed on an item.  I can't figure out how to get the backorder setting for the product though.  I can get the quantity no problem (I am checking for backorder allowed items but with quantity in stock).  No matter what I do I can only seemingly get the default config setting of 0 and not the items setting.  `StockStateInterface` has no `getBackorders` function and I can't seem to get `StockItemInterface` to give me the right info.

Here is my current `backorder.phtml`:

```
<?php
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$StockState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface');
$_qty = $StockState->getStockQty($_product->getId(), $_product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());

$ConfigState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockItemInterface');
$ConfigState->setProductId($_product->getId());
$_backorder = $ConfigState->getBackorders();

?>

<div class="product-info-backorder">
Qty:
<?php echo $_qty; ?>
Backorder:
<?php echo $_backorder;?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$obj = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();  
$stockRegistry = $obj->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface');
$stockitem = $stockRegistry->getStockItem($_product->getId(),$_product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
echo "Backorder: "; echo $stockitem->getBackorders(); echo '<br>';
```